# Is continuum hypothesis decidable in second-order ZFC?

Tags: logic, set-theory

From [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78074/a-question-about-second-order-zfc-and-the-continuum-hypothesis) I've found that some logicians claimed that the CH is decided in the second-order ZFC, namely $(ZFC_2\vdash CH)\vee (ZFC_2\vdash\neg CH)$. G. Kreisel's ["Informal rigour and completeness proofs"](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0049237X08715258) of 1967 contains the result regarding Zermelo's set theory, though I've not dived into details and could misunderstand smth. Also T.S. Weston stated the opposite in his work of 1977.

Is it widely known result? Is it considered correct by logicians? Or they accept Weston's arguments? I've failed to find any modern discussion of it, though it looks interesting as it provides a natural way to define the truth value of CH and in fact re-open the problem of CH.

Comment: In second order logic, with full semantics, there is no completeness theorem. So we should write $\text{ZFC}_2 \vDash \text{CH}$ or $\text{ZFC}_2 \vDash \lnot \text{CH}$, because that is what people would normally mean in this case. The point Weston is making is that second-order ZFC does not decide CH in the sense of $\vdash$ mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Noah: Beat me to it. :)

Comment: I've added a link to the paper. Incidentally, they **do** use the phrase "second order decidability" (p. 152), although by my quick reading they mean "decide" in a much broader sense than "prove in some fixed theory" (indeed that seems to partly be the point of the paper in the first place). And he doesn't appear to use the word "prove" or its relatives in connection with second-order logic.

Comment: @NoahSchweber As I understand the result is stated on p. 150. They use $\vdash_2$ symbol (p.149), namely $A\vdash_2B$ is pronounced "$B$ is a consequence of a second-order formula $A$".

Comment: @Seriy You're right, I missed that! Well, that's terrible notation to use in this context. Hopefully my and Asaf's answers have explained why.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Now I see Kreisel denotes as $\vdash_2$ _semantical_ consequence, not syntaсtic. I've already known that semantical consequence requires set theory as a meta-theory, but I've mistaken the $\vdash_2$ symbol as a syntactic consequence, and the word "decided" further puzzled me, and so this result attracted my attention. What a sad confusion! In fact, I've already examined the paper carefully, and failed to find the place where the term "consequence" is explicitly defined.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Only in his book (even its name "Elements of Mathematical Logic" misleading, the book is on model theory!) authors explicitly wrote that consequence means semantical consequence.

Thank you for your comprehensive answer. I've already met this Quine's comment about "set theory in sheep's clothing", but didn't know what exactly he meant and what's specifically wrong with second order logic. The incompleteness you mentioned doesn't seem to me problematic as it just means we should carefully distinguish between syntactic and semantical consequences. So thank you for the links.

Comment: @Seriy I'm glad I could be helpful! Two quick remarks: first, it's not just that we need to distinguish between syntactic and semantical consequences; we need to distinguish between *different notions of syntactic consequence*, since there isn't a "priviliged" one in any sense. Second, and not very importantly, I don't think that the name of the book is misleading - model theory is part of mathematical logic, indeed (in one view at least) its core (and I think it is even subtitled "model theory").

Comment: @NoahSchweber I see. But what if we combine all these notions of syntactic consequence and define a "privileged" syntactic consequence $\vdash$ such that $A\vdash B$ iff for some reasonable proof system $P$ $A\vdash_P B$? Would such definition be correct?

Comment: @NoahSchweber okay, the word _syntactic_ is not appropriate here, but in such way we can define some notion of consequence independent from semantic.

Comment: @Seriy OK, how do you define "reasonable"?

Comment: @NoahSchweber just any one of _different notions_ you mentioned. The only thing we need from such notions that the semantical consequence would follow from syntactic. Then it'll be the case for our "privileged" consequence.

Comment: @Seriy Well, this is impossible in any nice way: there is no computable (or anywhere near that) complete proof system for full second-order logic, at all.

Answer (score 15):

There are several problems with this:

First of all, second-order logic is not complete. This means that even if $\varphi$ is true in all the models of $T$, it does not mean that $T$ proves $\varphi$.

Secondly, second-order logic requires some sort of set theoretic meta-theory, since it allows second-order quantification, the notion of a set needs to be pre-existing.

If $\sf ZFC_2$ has a model then it is necessarily isomorphic to $V_\kappa$ for a strongly inaccessible cardinals $\kappa$. In particular, such model contains all the reals, all the sets of reals, and so on. So $\sf CH$ is either true in all the models of $\sf ZFC_2$, or it is false in all of them. In that sense, yes, second-order $\sf ZFC$ does "decide" the continuum hypothesis. But it is not the second-order theory that decides the value, as much as it inherits it from the meta-theory.

One of the good things about first-order logic is that to a large extent it is agnostic to its meta-theory. You can formalize it in $\sf ZFC$ or in $\sf PA$ or $\sf PRA$ or any system which provides sufficient induction. With second-order logic, you must inherit some of the properties of the meta-theory. So different people, working in different meta-theories, might disagree on what are "sets" to begin with. And so, if I work in a meta-theory where $\sf CH$ is true, the results would be different than someone working in a meta-theory where $\sf CH$ is false.

Comment: Dangit, beat me!

Comment: By a wide margin, man. But your answer is better...

Comment: I know, but Kreisel asserts CH or its negation is _provable_ in $ZFC_2$. I've already met this point several times that $ZFC_2$ requires sets in the meta-theory, but I can't get why. I think of the second-order logic as a formal deductive system, which deduces some sentences from other sentences, though the specific rules may vary. It extends the first-oder logic allowing quantifications over predicative symbols, how it forces us to have sets in the meta-theory?

Comment: @Seriy: In this case, just the fact that different meta theories give you different truth values point out that "let's insist to ignore the meta theory" is essentially pointless.

Comment: @Seriy "ZFC$_2$  requires sets in the meta-theory, but I can't get why." See the second part of my answer for this. Incidentally, just like I criticized Weston as misleading, Kreisel is *also* being misleading here: the word "prove" (and its variations) should never be used in the context of second-order logic unless one is using the Henkin semantics. The major exception to this rule is in the context of [$\Omega$-logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A9-logic), but I object to this as well; here "proof" is used in the sense of "a witness to validity" (cont'd),

Comment: and this really has nothing to do with "proof" in the usual sense of the word. " I think of the second-order logic as a formal deductive system, which deduces some sentences from other sentences, though the specific rules may vary. It extends the first-oder logic allowing quantifications over predicative symbols." It sounds like you're talking about Henkin semantics, possibly augmented with additional inference rules ("though the specific rules may vary") but ultimately still first-order. This is again not what Kreisel et al are talking about when they say "second-order logic."

Comment: @NoahSchweber Why do we need a semantics at all to prove sentences? Can't we just consider the syntax regardless to any semantics?

Comment: @Seriy Well, you *can*, but then you can't talk about e.g. [completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_completeness_theorem). Now one very reasonable point of view is that a logic isn't really a logic unless it has a "reasonable proof system." Second-order logic with the full semantics definitely doesn't, so in that case you wouldn't consider it a "logic" (and this was roughly Quine's position on the topic). On the other hand, coming from a semantic perspective, logics are fundamentally about classes of structures, and a nice proof system is a thing a logic may or may not have.

Comment: Ultimately the word "logic" isn't a technical term in general logic, though different parts of logic will give the word a precise definition (e.g. in abstract model theory it's generally treated semantically, and in proof theory it's generally treated syntactically). But the key point here is that, when Kreisel et al talk about second-order logic, they are speaking of the *inherently semantic* version. You can argue this is inappropriate, but it is what is going on here.

Comment: @Seriy: do you have a link to a paper of Kreisel in which he says that CH or its negation is provable in $\text{ZFC}_2$?  I would be interested to see his axioms. The most likely way in which that the claim attributed to him could be correct is if one takes the collection of all *true* sentences as the set of axioms of $\text{ZFC}_2$, which some people do, but which then makes provability trivial.

Comment: @CarlMummert "one takes the collection of all true sentences as the set of axioms" Wait, people *do* that? That's terrible.

Comment: @Noah Schweber: yes, it is common enough.  Here is an example I just saw: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78074/a-question-about-second-order-zfc-and-the-continuum-hypothesis#comment200771_78075 .

Comment: @CarlMummert I've downloaded it through sci-hub.org, do you wish to me send you it to you via e-mail?

Comment: @Seriy: if you could just post a citation to the paper here, I should be able to get a copy, and it will help others who find this question in the future.  Thanks -

Comment: @Seriy Depending on how long it is (and if it's searchable), a page number where Kreisel uses the word "provable" would also be useful.

Comment: @CarlMummert I've not found it freely available and downloaded it through the service that allows to download non-free papers. Is it ok to post links to to the paper's page and to this service?

Comment: @NoahSchweber G. Kreisel, "Informal rigour and completeness proofs", 1967. I've already mentioned it in the question, it contained a typo, just fixed it.

Comment: @Seriy I'm quite sorry, I read too quickly.

Comment: @Seriy: On page 149, Kreisel explains that he uses $\vdash_2$ to mean semantic consequence rather than provability. Overall, this paper by Kreisel is not the most obscure of his I have seen, but it is still relatively obscurely written, which I think was a characteristic of Kreisel's writing.

Answer (score 12):

*Short version: there's no contradiction, Weston and Kreisel et al mean different things when they say "second-order," and (in my opinion) Weston's paper is misleading on this point; and second-order logic is absolutely useless for attacking CH.*

---

[Weston's paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ndjfl/1093888026), in my opinion, is quite misleading: what he calls "second-order ZF" is really a **first-order theory resembling** second-order ZF. Yes, this is a different thing than ZF itself - and the crux of the matter, if you haven't seen it before, is the distinction between [standard semantics and Henkin semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_logic#Semantics).

That Weston is referring to the Henkin, rather than standard, semantics for second-order logic is hinted at when he writes

> This note presents a proof that **in the usual (proof-theoretic) sense** of
>   "decided", second-order Zermelo-Frankel set theory (ZF$^2$) does not decide
>   CH. $\quad$ *(Emphasis mine)*

and is made clear in his arguments. By contrast, Kreisel et al refer to the **genuinely second-order** theory (and see part 2 of this answer for an explanation of what they're talking about).

This distinction is huge! Full second-order logic **has no complete proof system** (and this is why Weston's remark makes it clear that he's treating a first-order version of second-order ZF; also, this means that it's misleading to use "$\vdash$" instead of "$\models$" when talking about full second-order logic). The natural "first-orderization" of second-order ZF, where we include predicate variables but despite appearances work with Henkin (so, first-order in disguise) semantics, is subject to all the usual restrictions of first-order logic.

By contrast, **true** second-order logic (that is, second-order logic with the "standard semantics") is intimately bound up with set theory: to tell whether a structure satisfies a given second-order sentence, we need to look at the full powerset of that structure, and of course the properties of the full powerset can depend heavily on the ambient set theory *(and this has led to quite reasonable criticism of second-order logic, e.g. Quine's famous comment that it is "set theory in sheep's clothing," although others such as Boolos disagree - see e.g. [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2026993.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3Ac97c8298d96e4fa19eb51670c7c6f7c3) for some discussion of the topic).*

Weston is clearly critical of full second-order logic *(EDIT: this may be a flawed interpretation, see Carl's comment below)*. This is quite reasonable, and indeed from a proof-theoretic perspective it's hard to see how one **couldn't** object to full second-order logic, given that it has no complete proof system. However, I find it quite inexcusable that at no point does he explicitly state that he is working in the Henkin semantics, and instead leaves that up to the reader to discover (leading to quite reasonable potential confusions).

---

So how does "true" second-order ZF decide the continuum hypothesis? Well, we argue as follows.

- First, note that there is a second-order sentence $\varphi_\mathbb{N}$ which characterizes the structure $(\mathbb{N}; <)$ up to isomorphism (this is because "has no infinite descending sequence" is expressible in second-order logic, if we use the standard semantics).
- Now consider the language $\Sigma=\{U, V, <, E,\prec\}$ where

  - $U, V$ are unary predicate symbols (which we think of as *sorts*), and
  - $<$, $\prec$, and $E$ are binary relations.
- We'll build a particular $\Sigma$-sentence $\tau$, consisting of the conjunction of the following sentences:

  - $U$ and $V$ partition the domain.
  - $\varphi_\mathbb{N}$ holds *relativized to $U$* (so the reduct to $\{<\}$ of the $U$-part of a model of $\tau$ is a copy of $(\mathbb{N}; <)$). *This is one of the three truly first-order conjuncts in $\tau$.*
  - $E\subseteq U\times V$ (thought of as "$x\in y$"), $<\subseteq U^2$ (thought of as, well, "$<$"), and $\prec\subseteq V^2$ (thought of as giving an ordering of the elements of the $V$-part).
  - Every subset of the $U$-part is represented by an element of the $V$-part: $\forall A\exists b(b\in V\wedge\forall x\in U(x\in A\iff xEb))$. (Of course "$b\in V$" and "$x\in U$" are abbreviations.) *This is truly-second-order conjunct number two.*
  - Finally, that for each $v\in V$ there is an injection from $\{w\in V: w\prec v\}$ to $\mathbb{N}$. *This is the third truly-second-order conjunct*.

It's easy to check that $\tau$ has a model if and only if the continuum hypothesis holds. So, **if you know which second-order sentences are satisfiable, then you can figure out whether CH is true**; it is in this sense that second-order logic (we don't even need second-order ZF!) "decides" CH.

We can do worse: we can cook up a second-order sentence $\psi$ which is true (in the standard semantics) in every structure (= is valid for full second-order logic) iff the [generalized continuum hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Continuum_Hypothesis) holds; or if there is no measurable cardinal; or etc.

---

OK, let me wrap up with one last point. You write

> it looks interesting as it provides a natural way to define the truth value of CH and in fact re-open the problem of CH.

Unfortunately, this is not the case. First of all, the claim "second-order logic decides CH" requires us to already believe that the full powerset of an arbitrary structure exists; this level of set-theoretic realism already commits us to the claim that the continuum hypothesis has a definite truth value. So this observation doesn't get us any closer to answering the question of whether CH has a definite truth value, because it implicitly already assumes that.

Second of all, there's the fact that second-order logic has no good proof system: there is in general no way to figure out that a given second-order sentence is satisfiable without already knowing facts about the set-theoretic universe. So to tell whether CH is a validity in full second-order logic, we would need to know whether CH is true.$^1$

*(For a further example of how second-order logic depends on set theory, see e.g. [this mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/161676/the-non-absoluteness-of-second-order-elementary-equivalence).)*

So second-order logic, while enticing at first, is ultimately not a *useful tool*. Instead, it's better to think of it as an *interesting object of study*.

$^1$OK, fine, there's ways around this. For instance, [a set-theoretic-multiversist](http://logic.harvard.edu/EFI_Hamkins_MultiverseSlides.pdf) would argue that *each universe's version* of full second-order logic decides CH *in that model*. But this doesn't really help, because then second-order logic can decide CH in different ways in different universes, and does require us to commit to CH having a definite truth value *in each universe* (which the multiverse view does anyways). So I'd argue that this doesn't really avoid my point above.

Comment: Completely so. One issue is that the question uses $\vdash$, and because provability is independent of semantics we don't need to fix a semantics to ask whether $\text{ZFC}_2 \vdash \text{CH}$.  To Weston's credit, he explicitly says he is talking about the "usual (proof-theoretic) sense of 'decided'" and as such he should not need to worry about semantics. It seems to me that Weston is not criticizing second-order logic directly, but is more directly criticizing Kreisel's use of "decided" to mean semantically rather than proof-theoretically decided.

Comment: @CarlMummert Yes (note that I quoted that passage of Weston in my answer); my objection, though, is that this still isn't clear to someone who isn't *already* familiar with the distinction. You may be right re: interpreting Weston, it seems I may have been too hasty; I've edited towards this point. I do have to object to the statement "because provability is independent of semantics we don't need to fix a semantics to ask whether ZFC$_2\vdash$CH;" although it's true, it omits the crucial point that we do need to fix a *proof system* - and unlike the first-order case there is no "right choice."

Comment: Weston does lay out his proof system and axioms for $\text{ZFC}_2$ in detail on pp. 499-500.  This is basically the kind of system Shapiro describes in his book, which I would normally view as the default effective proof system for second-order logic. There are indeed some variations, but I can't think of any common example of an effective proof system for $\text{ZFC}_2$ that would decide CH.

Comment: @CarlMummert Sorry, I didn't mean to imply that Weston doesn't fix a proof system; I just meant that I find that especially when talking to beginners, it's important to clarify that we really do need to fix a proof system for a first-orderization of second-order logic. (And neither can I.)

Comment: That is certainly true.

Comment: To clarify, does “the full powerset of an arbitrary structure exists” entail “the continuum hypothesis has a definite truth value”? Is the same true for GCH?

Comment: @user76284 Well, this gets a bit messy because in order to address questions like this we need some agreed-upon theory about definite truth values and semantic commitments. For example, even granting that powersets are unproblematic, $\mathsf{GCH}$ (as opposed to $\mathsf{CH}$) involves a quantification over proper classes. So, does that impinge on definite-ness?

Answer (score 0):

the points raised about about my paper were discussed, 'way back in the day, in another article: Journal of Philosophical Logic, May 1976, Volume 5, Issue 2, pp 281–298,Kreisel, the continuum hypothesis and second order set theory. In particular, semantic and syntactic results are distinguished, and a semantic "proof" that the CH is decided in 2nd order ZF is included there and also, I think, debunked. Tom Weston