# Maximal Realism and Continuum Hypotehsis

Tags: set-theory, real-numbers, second-order-logic

I have read in multiple places, per example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/624087/who-first-proved-that-the-second-order-theory-of-real-numbers-is-categorical), that there is a unique model of second order logic that axiomatizes the real numbers. If this is true, then we should be able to decide everything about the real numbers in second order logic, namely the continuuum hypothesis.

In this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2440430/is-continuum-hypothesis-decidable-in-second-order-zfc#targetText=In%20that%20sense%2C%20yes%2C%20second,agnostic%20to%20its%20meta%2Dtheory.) I read

«First of all, the claim "second-order logic decides CH" requires us to already believe that the full powerset of an arbitrary structure exists; this level of set-theoretic realism already commits us to the claim that the continuum hypothesis has a definite truth value.».

So my questions are:

1. If the real numbers only have one model in second order logic, we can say the continuuum hypothesis (CH) is true or false in second order logic, right? This settles for me the issue of CH. I assume we can't prove which one it is in second order logic because of incompletness.
2. About the citation I put above, if I believe in some kind of maximal model, where there are as many sets as there can possible be, I am assuming «full powerset of an arbitrary structure exists». So that should imply the continuuum hypothesis, is that correct? I say this because if my model is as large as it can be, the axiom of choice should be true, and GCH imples Choice. Although from that I cannot conclude GCH is true (and so CH), it gives me intuition that when the Universe of Sets gets larger, it goes in favor of CH.

Thank you

Comment: "if my model is as large as it can be, the axiom of choice should be true" Why should that be? AC can be interpreted both as expansive and *restrictive* (e.g. it rules out amorphous sets - shouldn't those exist in a maximally huge universe?). See also the discussion [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/338789/8133).

Comment: That is a good point. However since choice gives me pathological sets like non-measurable ones I always thought of choice as adding sets to my model. You were the one that made the citation I am quoting. Could you please explain it, that is, if I believe "the full powerset of an arbitrary structure exists", should I believe in CH or not?

Comment: It doesn't provide an argument one way or another, sadly. All you get is, as I said, the belief that CH has a definite truth value. Note that that alone doesn't have anything to do with second-order logic per se, it's a direct consequence of committing to the existence of full powersets in general. Where second-order logic comes in is when we subsequently say that the truth value of CH is equivalent to a validity question: that there are sentences $\varphi,\psi$ such that $\varphi$ is a second-order validity iff CH is true and $\psi$ is a second-order validity iff CH is false. (cont'd)

Comment: Basically, there are two separate things going on. First, we have the fact - which doesn't involve second-order logic at all - that enough set-theoretic ontology (namely, the existence of $\mathbb{N}$ and of arbitrary powersets) entails that CH has a definite truth value. Second, we then have the fact that that same commitment means that second-order logic with the standard semantics is actually well-defined; this in turn lets us equate CH with a question about validity in second-order logic. Note that *neither* piece sheds any light on whether CH is true or false.

Comment: Also, [forcing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forcing_(mathematics)) should indicate that there's not going to be a *simple* way to use considerations about maximality to decide CH one way or the other: any model of ZFC *(countable or not, well-founded or not)* can in a precise sense imagine an even larger model in which CH is decided differently. *(There are ideas for more complicated arguments about maximality and CH, but they're quite involved.)*

Comment: So I would be correct in saying that even if I believe "the full powerset of an arbitrary structure exists", I can know the CH is either true or false, but I can never know which one it is? The fact that something has a truth value we can't find is fascinating and frustrating at the same time.

Comment: Yes, that's basically right. Although it might be more palatable to phrase it as follows: that set theoretic commitment is enough to tell you *something* but not *everything* about CH. That's not so surprising - it says that one set of hypotheses isn't complete yet. It sounds btw like my comments have been helpful; would you like me to turn them into an answer? (I didn't do that initially since I wasn't certain they were along the lines of what you wanted.)

Comment: Yes, please do that. Actually my main point in this question was really to get the answer to the question «So I would be correct in saying that even if I believe "the full powerset of an arbitrary structure exists", I can know the CH is either true or false, but I can never know which one it is? », which you just answered. So I will happilly accept your answer. Thank you!

Comment: I've added an answer; let me know if you'd like me to go into more detail on some point, or truncate something (I added a bit of digression).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It doesn't provide an argument one way or another.**

---

Second-order logic is a bit of a side issue; the real point is the *ontological commitment(s)* mentioned in the OP. Those commitments immediately imply that CH has a definite truth value, since (granting said commitment) either there *is* an "anomalous" set of reals or there *isn't* one. That's all it gets you, unfortunately.

Even augmenting it with additional commitments, like "maximality," doesn't help much. Specifically, forcing indicates that there's not going to be a simple way to use considerations about maximality to decide CH one way or the other, since any model of ZFC (countable or not, well-founded or not) can in a precise sense imagine an even larger model in which CH is decided differently. (This holds for AC as well, if all we take for granted is ZF, by combining forcing with a bit of inner model theory.)

> **Digression**: This is *not to say* that maximality concerns are irrelevant to the topic, merely that their use will have to be rather subtle. There are a couple different ideas along these lines. The Inner Model Hypothesis, a personal favorite of mine, implies that the continuum is extremely large. Forcing axioms - specifically, PFA - start from the assumption that the universe should have as many "pretty generic" objects as possible, and wind up implying that $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_2$ while *also* implying a kind of "effective CH" (basically: no nontrivial cardinal characteristics of the continuum). And in the pro-CH direction we have Foreman's generic large cardinals program and Woodin's $\Sigma^2_1$ absoluteness theorem, which in my opinion are substantially more technical but still grow out of a "maximality" intuition. [This Mathoverflow thread](https://mathoverflow.net/q/23829/8133) is a good source of discussion on the topic. The point I'm making above is just that there aren't going to be any *simple* arguments one way or the other, and in my opinion this should be the main philosophical takeaway of forcing.

---

OK, now what about second-order logic?

The same set-theoretic commitment mentioned above also means that second-order logic (with the standard semantics) is a well-defined thing. In particular, it means that "second-order validity" is a well-defined notion. We already know that (under the above commitment) CH has a definite truth value, but we can additionally show that CH is "reducible" to second-order logic: there are sentences $\varphi,\psi$ such that $\varphi$ is a second-order validity iff CH is true and $\psi$ is a second-order validity iff CH is false.

But this really says more about second-order logic than about CH - the takeaway should be that second-order logic really is seriously entangled with set-theoretic reality (in contrast to first-order logic or even $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}$).

---

Basically, there are two separate things going on. First, we have the fact - which doesn't involve second-order logic at all - that enough set-theoretic ontologyentails that CH has a definite truth value. Second, we then have the fact that that same commitment means that second-order logic with the standard semantics is actually well-defined, which in turn lets us equate CH with a question about validity in second-order logic.

Note that neither piece sheds any light on whether CH is true or false. It's possible to view this pessimistically, but in my opinion that's not necessary since we can rephrase the situation as follows: the set theoretic commitment is enough to tell you something but not everything about CH. That's not so surprising - it says that one set of hypotheses isn't complete yet.

Comment: Thank you again!